# How to implement Linked List Using Stack

Tags: data-structures

I know it is possible for implement a stack using linked list. Is it possible to implement a linked list using stack ? 
If it possible,then how ? I did not get any references from anywhere.

Comment: Please give more information/code base required? Yes it is possible, but using what perl, python, c++, swift. objective C. C?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a singly linked list, implement `push` by adding at the head, and `pop` by removing from the head. You don't want to use the tail because you would need to keep iterating from the head to the tail to find the new top when you do a `pop`.

There's an example here: [Stack](http://martinbroadhurst.com/articles/stack.html)

If it's a doubly linked list, pick an end and implement `push` and `pop` by adding and removing at that end. Either end will be as efficient as the other because you have pointers going both ways so you can easily find the new top after a `pop`.

To answer your second question, I don't think you can implement a linked list using a stack. A stack is a strictly simpler ADT than a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a linked list by using two stacks. One stack is the "list," and the other is used for temporary storage.

To add an item at the head, simply push the item onto the stack. To remove from the head, pop from the stack.

To insert into the middle somewhere, pop items from the "list" stack and push them onto the temporary stack until you get to your insertion point. Push the new item onto the "list" stack, then pop from the temporary stack and push back onto the "list" stack. Deletion of an arbitrary node is similar.

This isn't terribly efficient, by the way, but it would in fact work.